# Why sometimes eigenvectors matrix cannot transform to initial matrix?

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra, eigenvalues

As we know,
$$H=U^{-1}\Lambda U $$
where $\Lambda $ is the diagonal matrix and $H$ is the original matrix, $U$ is the eigenvector matrix. Also, we can restore the original matrix via:
$$\Lambda=UHU^{-1}$$
However, I find such relation sometimes right in Mathematica and sometimes failure:

```
a = ( {
    {2, -1, 0, 0},
    {-1, 1, -1, 0},
    {0, -1, -1, -1},
    {0, 0, -1, -2}
   } );
Da = N[DiagonalMatrix[Eigenvalues[a]]];
Sa = N[Eigenvectors[a]] // Transpose;
Sa.Da.Inverse[Sa] // MatrixForm
```

The result breaks this relation, i.e. different from the original matrix:
[image]

But, if I change another original matrix:

```
a = ( {
    {1, -1, 0, 0},
    {-1, 1, -1, 0},
    {0, -1, 1, -1},
    {0, 0, -1, -1}
   } );
Da = N[DiagonalMatrix[Eigenvalues[a]]]
Sa = N[Eigenvectors[a]] // Transpose;
Sa.Da.Inverse[Sa] // MatrixForm
```

The result follow the relation above.
[image]

I am confused of such problem.

Comment: I just pasted the first block of code into a notebook and I got the exact same matrix `a` back. In addition: not every matrix can be diagonalized this way, so you can't expect this to work for every matrix. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigendecomposition_of_a_matrix

Comment: @SjoerdSmit Thanks for your comments! I change another computer and still obtain the "wrong" result, it seems strange. I will check whether it is the exception as you said.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Works fine for me:

```
a = {{1, -1, 0, 0}, {-1, 1, -1, 0}, {0, -1, 1, -1}, {0, 0, -1, -1}};

{Da, Sa} = Eigensystem[a];

Inverse[Transpose[Sa]].a.Transpose[Sa] == DiagonalMatrix[Da] // FullSimplify
(*    True    *)

Transpose[Sa].DiagonalMatrix[Da].Inverse[Transpose[Sa]] == a // FullSimplify
(*    True    *)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! By comparing with your code, I find the key problem is that we must use "Eigensystem", rather than use "Eigenvalues" and  "Eigenvectors" respectively.

Comment: @Merlin, a more fundamental error that you made is that you did not transpose the result of `Eigenvectors[]`.